# How to make qr code for free and unlimited?

Tags: gratis, qr-code

I am looking for some references to create qr code for free and unlimited, but I have not found it

Is there any reference what should I do? Do I need to make a qr code using a script? Or is there a free tool that I can use?

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Please note this site is about recommending *software,* not assets or [resources](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2470/185) like [howtos](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/882/185), [manuals/tutorials](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1258/185), [code fragments](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/904/185), etc. If you're looking for software, please consult [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) and **[edit]** your question accordingly.